# Android: Limiting Layout Scroll Range

Tags: android, android-layout, scroll, range

I would like to set a limit the the x and y ranges of a scrollable image. Here is the code I am using:

```
public class MapActivity extends Activity {


private LinearLayout container;   
private int currentX;   
private int currentY;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.map);
    container = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.Container);

    container.scrollTo(0, 0);

}

@Override  
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) { 
  switch (event.getAction()) { 
      case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: { 
          currentX = (int) event.getRawX(); 
          currentY = (int) event.getRawY(); 
          break; 
      } 

      case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: { 
          int x2 = (int) event.getRawX(); 
          int y2 = (int) event.getRawY(); 
          container.scrollBy(currentX - x2 , currentY - y2); 
          currentX = x2;               
          currentY = y2; 
          break; 
      }    
      case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: { 
          break; 
      } 
  } 
    return true;  
} 


}
```

And my map.xml looks like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center">
    <LinearLayout 
        android:id="@+id/Container" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"          
        android:layout_width="fill_parent">
    <ImageView 
        android:id="@+id/imageView1" 
        android:src="@drawable/aowmap"        
        android:layout_height="752px" 
        android:layout_width="1712px"></ImageView>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

I've tried various ways to get "Container"s x and y and even the images x and y, but no luck. I'm sure the code would go under ACTION_UP, but I'm just not sure what to put there to find the x and y.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a look at the display metrics, below is a snippet of code I use in an image gallery to restrict scrolling left, you should be able to do something similar!

The key line is `mlp.setMargins(...)`, the first parameter passed to that function is where i set the new left margin so you would need to do something similar but for the bottom margin!

```
DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics(); 
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics); 
MarginLayoutParams mlp = (MarginLayoutParams) gallery.getLayoutParams();
mlp.setMargins(-(metrics.widthPixels/2+130),mlp.topMargin,mlp.rightMargin, mlp.bottomMargin );
```

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Yeah, I'm not exactly sure how this helps. I just don't see it. I've tried using "x = container.getTop()" but this always returns 0... there just has to be a way to find the current x and y of the layout...

Comment: The code I posted would restrict the area that the user can scroll to - is that not what you want? Perhaps I misunderstood - if thats the case maybe a wee diagram of what your trying to achive would help

Comment: I'm pretty new at this, so I'm not sure at all how this code would be implemented into mine. Edit: I'll try looking into DisplayMetrics and see if I can find some tutorials.